# Creating A Test User on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook application development. I want to create a test user for my application but when I try it using the API

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&
name=FULL_NAME&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It displays the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "message": "(#15) The method you are calling must be called 
              with an app secret signed session"
  }
}
```

I have read & followed the steps mentioned on

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Still the problem persists. Please guide me, what should I do?

Thank You.

Comment: have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/introduction-to-facebook-test-users-accounts-with-php-sdk/40/). Also please note that facebook has recently introduced a GUI for [this](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/527/)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to get a valid access token - the application access token will do. To get this use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

substituting YOUR_APP_ID & YOUR_APP_SECRET with your respective values.

This will return a valid access token that you can substitute for APP_ACCESS_TOKEN in:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=FULL_NAME&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: for some reason name didn't work.. removed it, then it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need an `'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'` **and** a `'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'` one.

From the facebook documentation :

*In order to authenticate your app, you must pass the authorization code and your app secret to the Graph API token endpoint at `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`. The app secret is available from the [Developer App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and should not be shared with anyone or embedded in any code that you will distribute*

The link seems to be down at the moment though.

Comment: Hey thanks for quick reply. I know that I have to use my APP_ID & Access Token in the API. I have tried it still it is giving same error.I think there is some other issue, please help

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Facebook Test Java API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-test-java-api/) framework, which wraps the process of creating test users in a Java API. The test user also have access to the user details, the wall, and so on so you may create automatic tests to verify your application behavior.